# Can't get an image to float right of a UL

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, html-lists

I am trying to get the image to float to the right of both the p and ul tags... but the individual list items always break clear of the image and appear after the bottom of the image. I've tried many different ways (after reading other people's problems with this issue), but just can't get it to work with my example.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

See code snippets below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style-type: disc;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#awards {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #FBDDA0;
}
p.news {
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: fff;
}
p.news a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.news a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#awards ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
}
#awards ul li {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="awards">
  <a href="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" width="200" height="190" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" border="0" title="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article" alt="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article"
    />
  </a>
  <div>
    <p class="news">The late Dr. Allan Zavod received the <span style="color: #FBDDA0; font-weight: normal">Medal of the Order of Australia (OAM)</span> on January 26 2017, for service to the performing arts as a musician and composer. Here are some of his outstanding
      acheivements:</p>
    <ul style="padding-top: 7px;">
      <li>1st Australian to attend Berklee College of Music, Boston, on Duke Ellington's recommendation, 1970.</li>
      <li>1st Jazz Fusion Concerto on Australia Day for the Bicentenial at the Opera House performed by Australian Youth Orchestra in 1988.</li>
      <li>Won the Asia-Pacific Broadcasting Union (ABU) Song Contest in Kuala Lumpur (as composer), taking a very young singer Kate Ceberano on her first international performance, 1987.</li>
      <li>Awarded Doctor of Music by Melbourne University in recognition of his international achievements as a composer of Classical Jazz Fusion and for his substantial, original and distinguised contribution to music knowledge, 2009.</li>
      <li>Environmental Symphony, performed initially at The Banksia Environmental Awards in 2010. Later performed in full by the Melbourne Symphony Orchestra at Hamer Hall in 2015 - all proceeds (over $100,000.00) going to the Royal Melbourne Hospital for
        GBM Brain Cancer Research.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end awards -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how floats work. Text will wrap around and underneath the floated element.

Since your image has a hard width, you can apply a margin to the text wrapper that matches the image's width.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#awards {
  margin: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 650px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #FBDDA0;
}
p.news {
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: fff;
}
p.news a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.news a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#awards ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
}
#awards ul li {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

#awards > div {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="awards">
  <a href="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" width="200" height="190" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" border="0" title="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article" alt="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article"
    />
  </a>
  <div>
    <p class="news">The late Dr. Allan Zavod received the <span style="color: #FBDDA0; font-weight: normal">Medal of the Order of Australia (OAM)</span> on January 26 2017, for service to the performing arts as a musician and composer. Here are some of his outstanding
      acheivements:
    </p>
    <ul style="padding-top: 7px;">
      <li>1st Australian to attend Berklee College of Music, Boston, on Duke Ellington's recommendation, 1970.</li>
      <li>1st Jazz Fusion Concerto on Australia Day for the Bicentenial at the Opera House performed by Australian Youth Orchestra in 1988.</li>
      <li>Won the Asia-Pacific Broadcasting Union (ABU) Song Contest in Kuala Lumpur (as composer), taking a very young singer Kate Ceberano on her first international performance, 1987.</li>
      <li>Awarded Doctor of Music by Melbourne University in recognition of his international achievements as a composer of Classical Jazz Fusion and for his substantial, original and distinguised contribution to music knowledge, 2009.</li>
      <li>Environmental Symphony, performed initially at The Banksia Environmental Awards in 2010. Later performed in full by the Melbourne Symphony Orchestra at Hamer Hall in 2015 - all proceeds (over $100,000.00) going to the Royal Melbourne Hospital for
        GBM Brain Cancer Research.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

CSS:

```
p {
line-height: 140%;
color: #B4B4B4;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
}

ul {

font-size: 14px;
line-height: 140%;
font-weight: normal;
list-style-type: disc;
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#awards {
float: left;
margin: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
width: 650px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
background-color: #000;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
border: 2px solid #FBDDA0;
}
p.news {
line-height: 110%;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
color: fff;
}
p.news a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
p.news a:hover {
color: #C0C0C0;
text-decoration: underline;
}
#awards ul {
margin-top: 5px;
line-height: 110%;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
font-size: 13px;
color: #fff;
}
#awards ul li {
margin-bottom: 7px;
}
/*Start of my Edit*/
#text{
position:relative;
width:67%;
}
#picture{
position:relative;
width:30%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="awards">
          <div id="text">
            <p class="news">The late Dr. Allan Zavod received the <span style="color: #FBDDA0; font-weight: normal">Medal of the Order of Australia (OAM)</span> on January 26 2017, for service to the performing arts as a musician and composer. Here are some of his outstanding
              acheivements:</p>
            <ul style="padding-top: 7px;">
              <li>1st Australian to attend Berklee College of Music, Boston, on Duke Ellington's recommendation, 1970.</li>
              <li>1st Jazz Fusion Concerto on Australia Day for the Bicentenial at the Opera House performed by Australian Youth Orchestra in 1988.</li>
              <li>Won the Asia-Pacific Broadcasting Union (ABU) Song Contest in Kuala Lumpur (as composer), taking a very young singer Kate Ceberano on her first international performance, 1987.</li>
              <li>Awarded Doctor of Music by Melbourne University in recognition of his international achievements as a composer of Classical Jazz Fusion and for his substantial, original and distinguised contribution to music knowledge, 2009.</li>
              <li>Environmental Symphony, performed initially at The Banksia Environmental Awards in 2010. Later performed in full by the Melbourne Symphony Orchestra at Hamer Hall in 2015 - all proceeds (over $100,000.00) going to the Royal Melbourne Hospital for
                GBM Brain Cancer Research.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="picture">
            <a href="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" width="200" height="190" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" border="0" title="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article" alt="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article"
                />
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the two who replied with suggestions.

Unfortunately neither one would work exactly as I needed it to.  Since my example was surrounded by a 'div' with a border, I couldn't take out the 'display: block' on the outside container div.  I also couldn't change the generic 'p' and 'ul' tags, as that effected the rest of my site.  I could only work with the 'awards' and 'news' tags or any other new tags added.

I ended up using a bit of info from each suggestion.  Basically, I wrapped both side-by-side elements in their own 'div' tags, and make them both floating in their respective directions, added their respective widths, and added: 'display: inline-block'.   (I really wanted a solution that didn't add the hard-coded width, but couldn't figure out how to do that, and decided it wasn't worth the extra head-ache to find a way around it!)

Note: I also moved the 'p' tag to be above the two floated elements, and adjusted the positioning of the image to be more aesthetically pleasing.

Here is the updated code that works for me - with help from you both!

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style-type: disc;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#awards {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #FBDDA0;
}
p.news {
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: fff;
}
p.news a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.news a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#awards ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
}
#awards ul li {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

/* new css added to fix */

#awards #text{
 float: left;
 width:430px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#awards #picture{
 float: right;
 width: 210px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="awards">
 <p class="news">The late Dr. Allan Zavod received the <span style="color: #FBDDA0; font-weight: normal">Medal of the Order of Australia (OAM)</span> on January 26 2017, for service to the performing arts as a musician and composer.  Here are some of his outstanding achievements:</p>
 <div>
    <div id="text">
        <ul style="padding-top: 7px;">
            <li>1st Australian to attend Berklee College of Music, Boston, on Duke Ellington's recommendation, 1970.</li>
            <li>1st Jazz Fusion Concerto on Australia Day for the Bicentenial at the Opera House performed by Australian Youth Orchestra in 1988.</li>
            <li>Won the Asia-Pacific Broadcasting Union (ABU) Song Contest in Kuala Lumpur (as composer), taking a very young singer Kate Ceberano on her first international performance, 1987.</li>
            <li>Awarded Doctor of Music by Melbourne University in recognition of his international achievements as a composer of Classical Jazz Fusion and for his substantial, original and distinguished contribution to music knowledge, 2009.</li>
            <li>Environmental Symphony, performed initially at The Banksia Environmental Awards in 2010.  Later performed in full by the Melbourne Symphony Orchestra at Hamer Hall in 2015 - all proceeds (over $100,000.00) going to the Royal Melbourne Hospital for GBM Brain Cancer Research.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="picture">
        <a href="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.allanzavod.com/images/Allan_OAM-med-adj.jpg" width="200" height="190" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 30px;" border="0" title="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article" alt="Allan Zavod awarded OAM - click to read article" />
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div> <!-- end awards -->
```

Comment: What about my answer doesn't work for you? All I did was add a margin to a div that was already in your markup.

Comment: You made changes to the 'p' and 'ul' tags.. which I can't change as they effect the rest of the site. (Sorry, I didn't make that clear in the question).  Your stated solution only works if you remove the 'float left' under my original 'ul' definition.  if I add that back in (as it is needed for how I use the 'ul' tags elsewhere on the site), then it breaks the container box (content displays outside of awards div).  Your answer did give me a direction to take, which helped me get to where I wanted, hence the up-vote I gave you.  Thanks for your help

Comment: you don't have to make a global `ul` or `p` changes for this layout. I just did because you didn't say anywhere that you didn't want to modify a global `ul` or `p` property. You can easily just give the ul/p elements in this layout a class and target those elements by class name without affecting the rest of `ul`'s or `p`'s on your site.

Comment: So you're saying that because we changed global `p` and `ul` values in your CSS, our answers won't work for you? But you didn't mention anything about changing global styles until you made this post saying our answers don't work? Were we supposed to read your mind that we couldn't change a global `p` or `ul`? Why can't you just limit the CSS yourself, since you didn't mention anywhere in your post that you wanted the CSS limited? I don't see how any of us could have given you an acceptable answer with that limitation that you didn't mention. It's a trivial limitation to get around, too.